# Populate combobox with content from comma separated textfile - based on selection of another combobox

Tags: c#, csv, combobox

In a c# program I have two comboboxes, one with fixed values returning values like 01,02,03..

For the second combobox, I have a commaseparated file with values like:
01,sometext
01,sometext2
02,sometext3
04,sometext4

I want to fill my second combobox with the value from the commaseparated file, where the number matches the combobox1 selected value.

So I somehow need to read the commaseparated csv file, and then compare the results and add the values to the second combobox.

I've tried with the code below, but it returns random values, and it returns the numbers, not the textvalue.

```
combobox2.Items.Clear();

string combobox1_SelectedValue = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
string sImport = Program.Properties.Settings.Default.sImport;
string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(sImport);

foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
{
    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
    foreach (string uLine in tokens)
    {
        if (uLine.ToString().Substring(0) == combobox1_SelectedValue)
        {
            combobox2.Items.Add(uLine[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and where's the problem? reading csv, filling the combobox, selecting the values?

Comment: I think you might need to split each token again by space (' ') to get key and value for that token, then compare the number with selected value and return the corresponding text. I'd also like to suggest use of Linq instead for confusing loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is one line with comma and whitespaces, you don't need an array of lines but you should first split by whitespaces.

If your file is a pair of "number,text" by line, Your foreach loop should look like the following :

```
  foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
  {
        string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
        if (tokens[0] == combobox1_SelectedValue)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
        }   
   }
```